# C26432 If you define or delete any default operation in the type 'type-name', define or delete them all (c.21)

Tags: mfc, code-inspection

I have declared a destructor like this in the CPP file:

```
CResizingDialog::~CResizingDialog()
= default;
```

And in the H file:

```
virtual ~CResizingDialog(); // Destructor
```

Yet, it is flagging code inspection issues:

[image]

I see the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26432?view=msvc-160). I am not sure what I should do here.

Comment: Any reason you aren't just writing `virtual ~CResizingDialog() = default;` in the header?

Comment: @IInspectable Are you suggesting that I do that to the header and not to the source, or to both?

Comment: @IInspectable Initially it was a standard destructor. Then Visual Assist Code Inspection flagged the destructor to become a `default` and it applied that to the source file, leaving the header declaration as is. But then the VS version of code inspection flagged the issue in the header. So I am not sure of the complete way to do this right.

Comment: @IInspectable If I put it in the header, does it mean I don't need a destructor block in the source? Or should both say the same?

Comment: If you `= default` in your header, there is no reason to provide an implementation, neither in the header nor in the corresponding source file.

Comment: @IInspectable Understood.